# Send files between two systems over LAN

Tags: networking, router, ip, lan, dhcp

I am able to send the files from one to another system connected on same router in a LAN.

Now, I connected one more router to the first router to increase the range of wireless connectivity.

When I am trying to send the file over the LAN from one system to another then I am not able to do so..

In this case, One system is connected to 1st router and 2nd is connected to the 2nd router.

Is there any way to send files in this kind of configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the second router, change the IP address to be in the same range as the first (ie: 192.168.0.2), disable DHCP and connect the CAT5 cable from the first router to a LAN port on the second.

Comment: By configuring according to you, files are transferring but if In that case IPs assigned over second routers will depend on the first router.How can I increase the number of users in this case? I am a newbie for networking.

Comment: you can add switch to your network for increasing number of ports for connection.

Comment: but I want to do it for wireless devices.

Comment: can you elaborate what you exactly want?increasing no. of users in wireless is confusing.

Comment: with 1st router, 5 more routers are connected and on my 1st router a file reception application is running and devices connected from other routers can send the files to the file reception application.In this case, I was having the above problem.These devices connected to the 2nd to 5th router;may connected thru wifi too.

Comment: you can connect as many user u can through wifi or you can extenders if the there is a problem of wifi signal reception.Otherwise i think you need server or firewall or cisco router for (VLAN creation or dhcp realy).That would increase the complexity of you network.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15348/discussion-between-deceptive-mind-and-inovator).

Comment: my reputaion score won't allow me to do chat currently :)